# WPF - TemplateBinding doesn't recognize member content

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

Alright, so I have a window with the following resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I am getting an error saying that,  "The member "Content" is not recognized or is not accessible."
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to define TargetType on ControlTemplate

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
     <Grid>
         <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
     </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

or

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```