# Property not regonized or not accessible telerik

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xaml, telerik

I am using this code but get errors that, "The "ColorButtonStyle" is not recognized or not accessible" and "The "ExpanderButtonStyle" is not recognized or not accessible after I upgraded from telerik Q1 2014 to Q3 2014 using VS 2013.

```
  <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:RadColorPicker">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root"
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                                <telerik1:RadSplitButton x:Name="SplitButton" 
                                        Style="{TemplateBinding SplitButtonStyle}"
                                        ButtonPartStyle="{TemplateBinding ColorButtonStyle}"
                                       TogglePartStyle="{TemplateBinding ExpanderButtonStyle}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"


                                </telerik1:RadSplitButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

I have looked at the following link but still the problem persists. Any help would be appreciated!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19082227/4549221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ColorButtonStyle` and `ExpanderButtonStyle` were removed in Q2 2014.
You can re-organize your project to use the new `SplitButtonStyle` property.

Reference: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcolorpicker/changes-and-backwards-compatibility/changes-backward-compatibility.html